# MathJax wide matrices and tables extending outside of body area

Tags: bug, mathjax

It appears that Stack Exchange sites with MathJax support have been having some problems with tables and matrices being wider than the question and answer area of the site, leading to text mixing in with the sidebars.

- *[Out of question body area bound MathJax-ed matrices](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1330)*
- *http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24924*
- *http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25180*

It is possible that [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21740/9281) to the MathJax bug reporting question may be related, but I am not an expert, so can't tell whether it is the same issue or not?

I have checked these pages on both my Linux and Windows workstations, using a mix of web browsers. The wide Robotics matrix and \tag problem can be seen on all browser/OS combinations I've tried, but I only see the table fit problem on Linux (both Firefox ESR 45.4.0 and Chromium 53), I don't see them on Windows 10 (Firefox 49, Chrome 54 or Edge 38).

Comment: For your second link, the table in the original question was modified (based on one of the answers) so that it fits better.  But it is still very tight, and it may be that the default font size or scaling, or the fonts available on your system, may affect the results.  For example, if you have the STIX fonts installed on one system and not the other, that could affect the table size.  Since you are marking this as a bug, what do you think the result *should* be in these cases?

Comment: Thanks @DavideCervone I hadn't heard of the [STIX Fonts project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIX_Fonts_project) before, so I'm pretty sure they haven't been installed manually, though I suppose they might have been installed automatically. Certainly my Linux `~/.fonts` folder contains various `jsMath-cm*10.ttf` files, which seem to be TeX related.

Comment: @mark the stix fonts might be on the system level, e.g., via texlive. But the main question is: what is the result you are expecting? Tabular environments cannot line-break and thus can be abused to break the surrounding page layout.